# IVR support on facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, text-to-speech, facebook-messenger, ivr, facebook-chatbot

I am working on facebook bot. Is IVR or TTS possible on messenger through bot by using any API or other things?
I searched for it but was unable to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can check example project for details:

https://github.com/hungtraan/FacebookBot